# Help prove that the set $\mathbb{Q^3}$ is countable

Tags: proof-verification, elementary-set-theory

Help is this close, right? Need very elementary explanation

$\mathbb{Q}^3=\{(x,y,z)|(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{Q}\}$

A remark in the text states that the sets $\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Q}$ are countable but the set of irrationals is not.

There is another theorem (1.42) which states Let $A_1, A_2...$ be at most countable sets then: $A_1$ $\times$ $A_2$ is at most countable.

Proof:

Let $$A_1 = \{x | x \in \mathbb{Q}\}$$

$$A_2= \{y | y \in \mathbb{Q}\}$$

$$A_3 = \{z | z \in \mathbb{Q}\}$$

Since $A_1$, $A_2$, $A_3$ are at most countable:

$$A_1 \times A_2 \times A_3 = \mathbb{Q} \times \mathbb{Q} \times \mathbb{Q} = \mathbb{Q}^3$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$Q^3$ is by definition $Q \times Q \times Q$.so you have not prove the countability.

Notice that 
$$Q^{3}=\bigcup_{n_1,n_2,n_3 \in \Bbb{N},m_1,m_2,m_3 \in \Bbb{Z}}\{(\frac{m_1}{n_1},\frac{m_2}{n_2},\frac{m_3}{n_3})\}$$ which is a countable union of singletons.

Comment: thats what I was looking for

Answer (score 1):

If you know that the product of two countable sets is countable, and $\mathbb{Q}$ is countable, then you are done.

By the theorem (1.42) we have:

$\underbrace{\underbrace{\mathbb{Q}\times\mathbb{Q}}_{\text{countable}}\times\mathbb{Q}}_{\text{countable}}$

In fact we have that $\mathbb{Q}^n$ is countable for every $n\in\mathbb{N}$.